# WordPress - Missing Featured Image Thumbnail in Posts Page

Tags: wordpress

I added a featured image to my custom post type and it appears correctly on the front-end, but on the custom post type the featured image thumbnail doesn't show up at all.

[image]

As you can see, the *Remove featured image* button is read, but the thumbnail is not available. I used `the_post_thumbnail()` in my PHP code to display the featured image, which works correctly, but I don't know why the thumbnail missing. Anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: did you register your post type in the functions.php?  Can you share your code ?

Answer (score 0):

just add below code to your active theme's `function.php`

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'custom_featured_image_backend' );
function custom_featured_image_backend() {
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails','your_custom_post_type_name');
}
```